# Simulation modelling of ATM machine

Tags: mechanical-engineering, manufacturing-engineering, simulation, product-engineering

Today I built my First model with [Anylogic simulation software](https://www.anylogic.com/) on ATM simulation

So ATM is basically here a delay element, which takes delay time parameter as triangular( 1.5, 2, 3.5 ). My idea is I want to run ATM for only 8 hours in a day. In eight hour there is some downtime say (between 20-50 minute random) when ATM is not working say due to power failure/system issues. How to model downtime in ATM. My idea is to calculate number of People ATM serves each day.

Looking for kind help. I'm very enthusiastic and curious to learn it.
[image]